# Send push notification on progressive web app hosted on azure

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, azure-notificationhub

I am looking a way to push notifications to progressive web app hosted on Azure

I searched for same and found Azure Notification Hub do such things but for native Android/Apple devices, could not find it for web applications and progressive web app.

If not wrong, I know that Firebase (FCM) provides a way to do this but then web app should be hosted and registered in Firebase , because to send notification to FCM from server application, it requires a device token (device registration) which is available when application is deployed on Firebase.

Is it possible to send push notification from FCM to Azure hosted web app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send push notifications from FCM to an Azure hosted web app, you would need to register your web app with FCM and obtain a device token. You can then use this token to send push notifications to your web app from your server application using FCM.

The route I think is best, is you can also use Azure Notification Hubs to send push notifications to your web app. To do this, you would need to register your web app with Azure Notification Hubs and obtain a registration ID. You can then use this ID to send push notifications to your web app from your server application using Azure Notification Hubs.